# How to reference popup.html DOM from background.js in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to save a copy of my popup html when the popup closes.  Then reload it when the popup is triggered again.  background.js listens for a port disconnect from popup.js.  But when I try to get popup.html I think I'm getting background.html (even though I never set that up).

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (externalPort) {
    externalPort.onDisconnect.addListener(function () {
        let page = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
        console.log(page);
        chrome.storage.local.set({"page": page});
    })
});
```

what is logged

```
<head></head><body>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I get the innerHTML from within the popup.js I get the correct html but I don't know how to reference it correctly from background.js.

Edit: popup.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Treasure Roller</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: 1) Currently your script is just a normal script that runs inside the popup page. Just because it's named background.js it doesn't magically become a background script. A real background script must be declared in manifest.json, see the documentation. 2) You might want to save element state and values instead of saving HTML which stays unchanged for `<input>` and so on. 3) The modern approach is to save the values on change, immediately, with an optional Undo or Reset button.

Comment: 1) No it's not.  background.js is declared in the manifest.  and you don't need to be condescending.  2) I have a lot of javascript modifying the DOM so it's easier to just save html than save all the values and run them through the scripts again  3) that's what I was doing originally but the values get changed frequently and I only need the ones when the popup is closed

Comment: Without seeing the amount of changes I would think there should be no problem with saving the state on each change, although I would rework the app to save just the state. Anyway, if you don't have `<input>`s you can save the entire HTML, of course. The only reliable way to save the data on closing of the popup is to use a synchronous storage like HTML5 `localStorage` and `window.onbeforeunload` listener right inside the popup script. BTW if you declared background.js in manifest.json then you should not load it in the popup html if you understand the architecture.

Answer (score 3):

The first challenge you might be having is that you loaded your background script into your popup. Even though your background script is declared in the manifest file, you might have some issues; since chrome will treat it as part of the `popup.html`.

This means that:

1. No communication is taking place between your `popup.js` and `background.js` (loaded in popup).
2. An error might be occuring preventing you from running anymore javascript from within the popup context. This is because background.js, when used correctly, has access to more `chrome APIs` than a popup would. If used in popup context and these APIs are called, an exception will be thrown. When an exception is thrown and not caught, the script is halted, preventing you from doing any more js involved actions. Background.js should not be loaded in popup.html except you have a background.js file that is not the background page.

What you can do to determine if this is the case is to right-click on the popup page and click Inspect. Go to the console tab and read any errors that might have occured. If no error occurred, i would still advise that you remove the background.js script from your popup.html.

As an aside, the background script does not need to be loaded into any html page. It automatically runs on browser startup even before the user will enter a web address.

If none of the above pertains to you,

errors usually have a stack trace from where the error occurred. Click on anything that says `chrome://extensions...`. It should take you to where exactly in your code you're having issues.

And if that doesn't help you, test this out:

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({saveState: true, state: {---"state data goes in here---"}});
```

You can send the whole html this way I believe.

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.saveState){
        chrome.storage.local.set(request.state, function(){ sendResponse(true)});
    }
});
```

Simply put, each time a change is made to your popup UI,

(for example, a user clicked edit text for an item on your todo list extension and it turns into an input text box),

you send `{view: "edit", item: "no 2", addButton: "hidden"}` as the state object to background, who then saves it to storage.

When the popup opens, all you would need is to ask storage for the state and render your UI based on the data.

```
chrome.storage.local.get('state', function(result){
    if(result.state){
        //This is a function you will write
        render(result.state); 
    }
    else{
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

Note that you are also using `chrome.runtime.connect` which is reserved for more long-lived connections. There is nothing wrong with this but if you only need to save state `beforeunload`, sending one time messages for now may be easier to debug.

Comment: `background.js` is not loaded in popup.html.  You can see in the html I added that it isn't called.  I have no problem communicating back and forth between `popup.js` and `background.js` when saving.  The output is based on random dice rolls so I can't just save the inputs.  I was looking for a way to just save the final html when the popup closes because that is "cleaner".  But there is no "close" event for the popup so the only way to do that is establish a port like I have and then listen for a disconnect.

Comment: The issue I'm having is when I try to save the `popup.html` with `background.js` it is getting the `background.html` instead.  that is why you see the same three scripts in the html that are under "background" in the `manifest.json`. That's why there is nothing in the body.  Because it is not the `popup.html`.  The `document.getElements` is referencing the `background.html`, not the `popup.html`.  I wanted to know if there is a way to specify the correct html when I reference `document`.   I guess I'll just go back to saving each time the user rolls the dice.

Comment: I apologize. I misread parts of your question. I was actually looking at `background.html` having a `popup.js` in the log. Seems that it is a non-issue. I don't think there's any way to do what you're asking since `beforeunload` doesn't fire in the popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the HTML of the popup when it is closed you can try some thing like the following:

Create an `window.onbeforeunload` listener in the popup page, in the event listener read the html. you can process the html in the listener or send it as a message to the background page (using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`) from the listener

Comment: onbeforeunload doesn't trigger for popups in chrome extension

Comment: Yes onbeforeunload is not triggering in popups but unload event fires, one thing I noticed is chrome.runtime.sendMessage is not working inside unload handler but you can do some thing like the following
`var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
window.addEventListener("unload", function (event) {
 background.processPopupHtml($("body").html());
}, true);`